# Convert AS 3.0 into AS 2.0 for JSON Encode & Decode

Tags: json, actionscript-2, actionscript-3

I have written an AS 3.0 code for JSON Encode and Decode, but I need the below code written in AS 2.0. I know AS 3.0 but don't know AS 2.

Here is the code:

```
            stop();
            var getFBId:String = ExternalInterface.call("getFBIdFromJS");
            var getFBName:String = ExternalInterface.call("getFBNameFromJS");

            import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;
            import flash.events.Event;
            import flash.net.URLLoader;
            import flash.net.URLRequest;
            import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
            import flash.net.URLVariables;

            import fl.transitions.*;
            import fl.transitions.Tween;
            import fl.transitions.easing.*;
            import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;

            import flash.display.MovieClip;
            import flash.events.MouseEvent;
            playerInformation.visible = true;

            var loginObj:Object = new Object();

            var fbId:String = new String();
            var Id:String = new String();
            var varUid:String = new String();
            var ImageUrl:String = new String();
            var CreditBalance:String = new String();
            //var PointBalance:String = new String();
            var CoinBalance:String = new String();
            var IsDailyBonus:String = new String();
            var DailyBonusAmount:int = new int();



            var fbvarsLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            var fbvarsReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("fbvars.php");
            var fbvarsVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
            fbvarsLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
            fbvarsReq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;


            fbvarsReq.data = fbvarsVariables;
            fbvarsLoader.load(fbvarsReq);
            fbvarsLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, receiveLoad);

            function receiveLoad(evt:Event):void
            {
                fbId = getFBId;
                varUid = getFBName;
                ImageUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + getFBId + "/picture";

                trace (getFBId);
                trace (getFBName);
                trace (ImageUrl);

                loginObj.FacebookId     = fbId;
                loginObj.UserName       = varUid;
                loginObj.PlatformId     = 1;
                loginReq.data = JSON.encode(loginObj);

                loginLoader.load(loginReq);
                trace("login ENCODE: " + JSON.encode(loginObj));

                FBlogindata.text = JSON.encode(loginObj);


            }
            //--------------- FB Vars (E)

            var serverURL:String = "http://serverURL";
            var playerPicLoader:Loader = new Loader();

            //--------------------------------

            var loginReq: URLRequest    = new URLRequest();
            loginReq.method             = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            loginReq.url                = 

            "http://serverURL";

            var loginLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            loginLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete_login);

            function onComplete_login(e_login:Event)
            {
                var loginReturn:Object=JSON.decode(e_login.target.data,true);
                trace("login DECODE: " + e_login.target.data);
                logindata.text = e_login.target.data;

                if (loginReturn.Player.Status == "Valid")
                {

                    Id = String(loginReturn.Player.Id); 
                    CreditBalance = String(loginReturn.Player.CreditBalance);       
                    var playerPic:URLRequest = new URLRequest(ImageUrl);
                    playerPicLoader.load(playerPic);

                    playerInformation.mcPlayerThumbHolder.addChild(playerPicLoader);        
                    playerInformation.txtPlayerName.text = varUid;
                    playerInformation.txtPlayerCredit.text = CreditBalance;
                    playerInformation.visible = true;

                    UIDShow.text = Id;
                    FBIDShow.text = fbId;       

                    if (this.parent.parent != null){

                        trace (CreditBalance);


                        MovieClip(this.parent.parent).credit = CreditBalance;

                    }
                }
            }
```

Can any one write the above code in AS 2.0?

Comment: Why would you rewrite the JSON encoder / decoder that is inbuilt in AS3?

Comment: Is your swf embedded in an html file ?

Comment: This was/is a request for free work, so closing as 'too broad'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [implementation of AS2 JSON parser](http://inner.geek.nz/uploads/JSON.as). There are two static methods `stringify()` - to encode into JSON and `parse()` to decode. So you don't have to write your own implementation. For other stuff you should probably sit and learn some things about AS2 or find someone who still remember AS2 :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't learn AS2 ever. I have started with AS3. What should I write instead of URL Loader? any I dea?. Thanks in advance :)